# What Civicrm Theme(s) are better than Garland?

Tags: drupal, theme, usability

I've been using Garland for a long time, but our staff complain that it's drab. Anyone have a suggestion for something brighter but also very clean (ie. good workflow, low rendering overhead)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I often like https://www.drupal.org/project/liquid_coolness

Simple, clean theme, that is still pleasing to see. Has liquid width, so if you have a big screen you can make use of it for CiviCRM screens.

Not really maintained though.

Answer (score 5):

Bright and clean: I use Seven (ships with Drupal 7 Core - so well supported) as CiviCRM Administration theme - for nearly all of our projects. Easy to subtheme as well - making it a MySeven - if/when required.

Comment: I installed Adminimal on my site but had an issue with the "Sidebar Left" in that "CiviCRM Create New Record" would always pop up to the top of the bar and be unclickable. Might be a 4.6 thing, but it's sure annoying!

Answer (score 5):

I've always used [Adminimal](https://www.drupal.org/project/adminimal_theme). I think it makes the Drupal backend as a whole much easier to use, and it's always worked well for me with the Civi backend too.

Comment: That's a good one. Any idea how to make adminimal's menu style override civi?

Comment: @CullenMcGough Ah, nothing already-made that I know of, sorry. Though it might not be too hard to come up with custom CSS to override just Civi's menu to look similar to Adminimal's.

Comment: Just my opinion, YMMV, but I don't like this type of "modern" interface. I find them harder to read and navigate and to tell interactive widgets apart from purely visual elements.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a CiviBartik theme that I use often: https://www.drupal.org/project/civi_bartik

Answer (score 2):

A couple of others not listed in other answers

https://github.com/vingle/st.visuali.finsburypark/

and

https://github.com/artfulrobot/aah

Answer (score 0):

I use Bluemarine, which is an old classic:
https://www.drupal.org/project/bluemarine

Not very exciting, but efficient use of screen space if you disable sidebars

Answer (score 0):

I've been using a couple of themes based on the AdaptiveTheme https://www.drupal.org/project/adaptivetheme.  I find both Pixture Reloaded and Corolla to be easy to use and adapt for large screens.